# Can I install Anaconda on an offline Windows PC?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install a newer version of Anaconda (Individual Edition) on an offline Windows PC at work. Can I just transfer the 64-Bit Graphical Installer (466 MB) to the PC and complete the installation without internet connection? (I am asking because I would like to be sure about this before I deinstall the old version that is currently installed)

edit: Simply running the Installer worked. No need for console commands or anything. Thanks!

Comment: The [official installation instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/) mention offline installs, is that information not sufficient? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

of course you can, if you are using Anaconda's offline install packge, it doesn't need internet connection when you installing

Comment: where to find this offline install package?